# struts error: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, struts2

Need help in running the sample struts program, it is throwing "The requested resource is not available" error.

I am using struts-2.3.24.1 and Tomcat 8.

[image: The Project structure]

**Web.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

      <display-name>SampleStruts</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

       <filter>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
       </filter>

       <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       </filter-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

       <struts>
          <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
          <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="login" class="com.sr.actions.LoginAction" >
                <result name="success"> /welcome.jsp </result>
                <result name="failed"> /failed.jsp </result>
            </action>
       </package>

       </struts>
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: The `struts.xml` file must be at the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inconsistent library dependencies most popular error in dependencies management. You don't have an important library in the project dependencies.

The `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` is required to resolve error.

See how to [Create Struts application using Maven](http://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html).

Comment: Thank you.. now the login.jsp is opening. But while submitting the page it is throwing the error: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with context path [/SampleStruts].

Comment: move `struts.xml` to the `src` folder.